# Algorithm for complex validation

Tags: algorithm

I'm building validation for employee attendance system and the programming language is independent. I have designed algorithm for lot of cases and its working very fine.

Now, I'm stuck with some cases. I just need some one give some sparks to my thoughts so that I can finish it off.

Let's assume the below scenario:

Employee attendance is monitored using schedule as shown below,

1. `06:30 Shift 1 - IN`
2. `12:00 Shift 1 - OUT`
3. `13:00 Shift 2 - IN`
4. `15:30 Shift 2 - OUT`

Now, if the employee punch five times, I have to cancel one punch based on the closeness of the punches to the shift schedule, means I want to delete redundant punch.
For example, the employee punch as below:

1. `06:12`
2. `11:57`
3. **`12:48`**
4. `12:57`
5. `17:02`

If I do manual delete, I will delete the 3rd punch (12:48), because all other punches are close to the schedule.

Now, my logic is to treat the first punch as Shift 1 - IN punch and last punch as Shift 2 - OUT punch.
Then need to work over the middle three punches and delete one.

---

> Edit:

*** I have found some thing,

- I can take first and last punches as S1-IN and S2-OUT. Now validated Employee `1st punch and 5th punch`. The remaining is 2nd, 3rd and 4th punches.
- Find the absolute difference of `2nd, 3rd and 4th` punches with
  schedule `S1-OUT` and `S1-IN`. Take the minimum of the above
  difference values. Delete the other punch.

Comment: Hi Rauf! Can you please explain a bit more clearly? In the employee punch sample, how come there are 5 punches? It should have been an even number, right?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi This is done by employees. For some employee, they may forget whether he/she did the punch or not. Then they will punch again.

Comment: Does not your punch system have an attend/leave (In/Out) toggle option?

Comment: @BassemAkl No. That is what I'm trying to make. We are using these hand punch machines in outdoor. So we are using very old ( but very much durable) hand punch machine. It will just give .txt file with time and date. All other procedures we have to do outside of the machine.

Comment: Is your worst case is 5 punches? Or you're trying to find a general (yet complex) solution for any case?

Comment: @BassemAkl For the time being, 5 punches

Comment: Add a tolerance time, for example `e = 15 mins`. For IN get the lowest from all values in the range: [IN - e, IN + e]. For OUT get the highest from [OUT - e, OUT + e].